# Naming a method that returns 0 for negative values

Tags: naming

I'm writing such a method library. I can't seem to find a good name for it nor any reference of anyone having named such a function before.

What would be a good name for it?

Comment: *Clipper*, or maybe more specifically, *NegativeClipper?* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(electronics) You also have suggestions in there of *slicer* and *limiter*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it a *clipper* as a noun and *clip* as a verb.

The operation you're describing would be a *NegativeClip* or *SubzeroClip*. Of course you could just have a generic function with two or three arguments. Depending on your needs I could see *LowerBoundClip* or *FloorClip* or *BottomClip* being paired with *UpperBoundClip* or *CeilingClip* or *TopClip* instead. In a couple of those the word *clip* almost sounds redundant.

Words like *bound, bounds, bounded, boundary* are used in mathematics but as I think about possible function names I'm not sure they were as clear in meaning. And *binding* is already used in other programming topics so there's some potential for confusion that also.

Comment: In .Net you could achieve this with `Math.Max(0, YourNumber)` for the more generic function.

Comment: @MartinSmith Aliasing that approach is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I guess I would call it *positiveOrZero*…